# using "paths" in tsconfig.server.json for server side redering not working

Tags: angular

In order to avoid relative path when I import file, I try to configure angular to understand the path.

So I configured this as :

```
//tsconfig.server.json
"compilerOptions":{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@env/*": ["./enviroment/*"]
        ...
    },
}



//and in a component I use like this: 
import { X } from '@env/enviroment'
```

when running ng serve, Everything working fine.

But in case of server-side rendering, it throws the error as

> Cannot find module '@env/environment'.

Is "paths" are not supported by server-side rendering?

PS: Ref. from here 
https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/734#issuecomment-306176547

Never mind, it seems the problem is that although for client side rendering the line:

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
```

works well, for server side rendering the line must be:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Is it possible to use "paths" in server-side rendering ?

Comment: You did specify the correct tsconfig for the server app in your .angular-cli.json, right?

Comment: yes, I am confident about it !! @David

Answer (score 1):

As default your `tsconfig.server.json` extends `tsconfig.app.json` and if you use paths, they exists in `tsconfig.app.json`.

One thing what you should do is remove `baseUrl` parameter from `tsconfig.server.json`. Because in that file is defined as **"."**, but in `tsconfig.json` is defined as **"./"**.