# Using path mapping in tsconfig with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to use path-mapping to directly reference a library which sits in the same directory structure as my angular application.

Structure:

```
mycompany-mylib/
src/
tsconfig.json
```

I've added the following to my `tsconfig.json`

```
{      
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@mycompany/mylib": ["mycompany-mylib/lib/src/public_api"],
    }
  }
}
```

This configuration seems to be correct and Typescript can resolve these paths as I get no errors and full intellisense in Visual Studio Code.

For example:

```
import { UserClientModule } from '@mycompany/mylib'
```

However when I run `ng serve` or `ng serve --aot` I get an error, that the module was not found (My AngularCLI Version is **1.7.4**):

```
ERROR in src/app/core/components/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts(5,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@mycompany/mylib'.
```

This technique should work as there are several blog posts and github issues referencing it. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. I can fix this in webpack by providing an alias configuraton, but since there is no `webpack.config.js` in angular cli, I can't do that.

Comment: not sure but seems similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/49795010/5043867

Comment: maybe set `"baseUrl": "./src"` and `paths relate to it` wiil get it to work, it origin to be `"./"` , but my is not work, I don't know why!

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix it myself. Angular CLI, by default, uses another config:  `./src/tsconfig.app.json`, I added my configuration there too and slightly modified the paths like this:

```
{      
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "@mycompany/mylib": ["../mycompany-mylib/lib/src/public_api"],
    }
  }
}
```

It now compiles fine, as long is there is not a `node_modules` folder in `mycompany-mylib`. I would still thankfull for a solution to this.

Comment: strangely, Ive got a configuration where this does not work either, in angular 5.

Comment: I have many projects created by angular-cli (a `tsconfig.json` file in your root and a `tsconfig.app.json` file in your src folder ). I don't have to modify the `tsconfig.app.json` on my projects folder. I added all the necessary I need to the `tsconfig.json` file on the root folder and it works fine.